# Here api not showing any data in /places/v1/dicover/here for specific lat long

Tags: here-api

I am using here map api for getting nearby places but it is giving blank data (/places/v1/descover/here). While in /descover/explore/ it is giving so many records on same lat long. I am sharing screenshot for better understanding, Visit https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3804672/65583a3e4f228ade754feba101ef26eb.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the use case you have.
The Here entrypoint helps users to identify direct places at their location or at a point selected on a map by returning places close to a given point, sorted by distance. (Normally the closest known places are returned, but if the uncertainty in the position is high then some nearer places are excluded from the result in favour of more popular places in the area of uncertainty.) 
Then again the Explore entrypoint retrieves a complete list of relevant places nearby a given position or area. It answers the question "What interesting places are in the viewport of the map?" The results presented to the user are confined to those located in the current map view or search area and are ordered by popularity.

In general I would recommend to use the Explore entrypoint as the Here one is deprecated:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/entrypoint-maturity-availability.html

Comment: As Here entrypoint is depricated so I will not use it. But, currently I am using Explore entrypoint and I am not getting all places that are near by given lat/long. Relevant places filtered by categories in Explore api is not complete. In my experience some popular locations are missing in api response. Thanks.